# Entity Framework MySQL include results in InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, table-per-type

I've got a Table-per-type hirarchy like this:

Theres Sensors, which contain Updates (as a list), which contain datapoints (as a list).
Datapoints are made up of different derivations of the class "Datapoint", for example theres Int_Datapoints and Float_Datapoints. In the database, those are each in their own table (Table-per-type), linked to the "Update" with their ID.

My Context contains a dbset of Sensors.

If I want to have all the datapoints of all the updates using MySQL EF, I assume I need to create something like this:

```
List<Sensor> result = _seonsorContext.Sensors.Include("Updates.Datapoints").Where(x => x.Guid == Sensor.Guid).ToList();
```

When I do this, just including Updates (With the actual datapoints missing) it works. But when I want the datapoints, Including them too, I get the said exception:

```
InvalidCastException

StackTrace:

   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetByte(Int32 i)
   at MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlDataReader.GetByte(Int32 ordinal)
```

Do I need to look out for something here, regarding the Table-Per-Type hirarchy?